# Why are there scroll bars despite fitting a canvas exactly to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, position, scrollbar

I have a page with exactly one visible element: a canvas. I am setting the canvas' width & height to be exactly the width and height of the window (`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`), however horizontal and vertical scroll bars still appear and allow me to scroll around a very small amount. None of my elements have any border, padding, or margin (including `body`, which I specifically set to have none). Is there a better way to make a canvas take up the entire screen, or should I simply subtract a fixed amount from the width & height, and what would that be?

Comment: Hi! We can't help you with code we can't see. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). It sounds like margins or padding are coming into it, but again, it's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Now that we have a sweet _description_ of the code, can we have the code please?

Comment: I don't know why I submitted the code at the time, I probably should have (It was late at night). The solution in there works, as does the solution from Mr Proud. I don't know which one is "better" so I'll use the latter. I'll try to include minimum reproducible examples in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style with overflow of `hidden`.

```
<style>
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```